# i want the program to accept a str value "exit" which would terminate the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, backend

in this program, variable SPAN accept int only. but i want it that once a user types exit, it terminate the code.

```
    while True:
        try:
            span = int(input('Enter number of span:'))
       except  ValueError:
            print("invalid input, please enter valid input")
        continue
    else:
        break

while span <= 1 or span >= 5:
    print('Enter span range between 2-4')
    spann()

if span == 2:
    span2()
elif span == 3:
    span3()
elif span == 4:
    span4()
```

Comment: What is ```spann()``` ?

Comment: Check the input as a string before trying to convert to int

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code, it will exit when `span` equal `exit` and return error if `span` not equal `exit` and not a number.

```
while True:
    span = input('Enter number of span:')
    if span == 'exit':
        exit() 
    else:
        try:
            span = int(span)
        except ValueError:
            print("invalid input, please enter valid input")
```